# get single panoramic photo from Street View pano

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I uploaded a street view with the code taken from Google Apis. If i click far from my position or use the arrows the pano change and I would avoid this, then is possible delete the connections with the other pano or obtain single panoramic photo to run itself like google views?

The code is simply that:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View containers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
    function initialize() {
     var bryantPark = new google.maps.LatLng(37.869260, -122.254811);
      var panoramaOptions = {
       position: bryantPark,
       pov: {
        heading: 165,
       pitch: 0
    },
    zoom: 1
  };
  var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      panoramaOptions);
  myPano.setVisible(true);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wish that this panoramic photo function precisely or as those of https://www.google.com/maps/views/home?gl=us&hl=it like this one: https://www.google.com/maps/views/view/105558295291738522367/gphoto/5999530155782979586?gl=us&hl=it&heading=33&pitch=90&fovy=75
This is not linked to other panoramas , unlike the street view which is connected to other pano images.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking to do?  Perhaps provide your code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: more info in description, ty for attenction

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want links, set the linksControl [StreetViewPanoramOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaOptions) to false.

```
linksControl: false
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var bryantPark = new google.maps.LatLng(37.869260, -122.254811);
  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: bryantPark,
    linksControl: false,
    clickToGo: true,
    pov: {
      heading: 165,
      pitch: 0
    },
    zoom: 1
  };
  var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    panoramaOptions);
  myPano.setVisible(true);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I Need ClickToGo, in Google views it is used to center camera where i clicked with the mouse

Comment: By default is set true